# rails association with user and post model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going to do association with  **user** and **post** model.

I added `user_id` to **post** model like this

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_posts
```

In model

**user.rb**

```
has_many :posts
```

**post.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

In **post** views / it work perfect

```
 <%@posts.each do |post|%>
    <%=post.post_name%>
    <%=post.user.name.first(20).capitalize, post_path(post.user.id)
 <%end%>
```

In **user** views /I am getting error

> undefined method `post_name' for
> #Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fc9c432bde8

```
  <%@users.each do|user|%>
     <%=user.posts.post_name%>
     <%=user.name.first(20).capitalize,post_path(user.id)%>
   <%end%>
```

If I want to display like this way what I want to do. Pls need help I am new to rails

I want to add post_id to user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because you're trying to call `post_name` on a collection of `posts` that belong to a `user`. A collection is like an array, so you'll have to iterate through that collection and call `post_name` on each post.

```
<% @users.each do |user|%>
  <% user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.post_name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= user.name.first(20).capitalize, post_path(user.id) %>
<% end %>
```

The reason you're getting a collection of posts is because of your associations. A user `has_many` posts, which means you are going to get back all the `posts` that belong to a user. That may mean 0 posts or 10 posts depending on how many times the `user` has posted.

Because of this, you may want to check if the `user` has any posts before you iterate through them.

Comment: Do you have the code on in the view more than once?

Comment: @hashrocket I have problem with edit and delete one to many relationship. I made question here you might know the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719448/how-to-update-and-edit-one-to-many-relationship-mvc-in-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment110913863_62719448

Answer (score 0):

`NoMethodError` means that method does not exist on that `posts`. But how and why?

In your first example, `post` is an object of `Post` — it must `respond_to` the method you're calling on it.

To see what methods are available on an object, you can call `#methods` (which is also available on the class-level):

`puts post.methods`

That will give you an array of the methods you can call on `post`.

There is also a method called `#class` we can call to see what class an object is:

`puts user.posts.class`

Which will return `ActiveRecord::Relation` which acts like an array under the hood. Because a `User` has many `Post`, we have an array of `Post`, thus calling `name` on an array of `Post` objects will not work.

If you want the first `name` of the `posts` that a `User` has:

`user.posts.first.name`

But beware, because a user may not have any posts.